# SQL Server Stored Procedure City Return

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to figure out how to create a stored procedure in the AdventureWorks database that given a `city` as input returns the `address`, `stateprovince` and `salesterritory` columns for that city.

I've been following a book example, but I feel like I am straying quickly!

Here is what I have so far...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetRegion
    @address nvarchar(60) not  null,
    @province nvarchar(50) not null,
    @territory varchar(50) not null
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Person.Address
    SET AddressLine1 = @address

    UPDATE Person.StateProvince
    SET Name = @province

    UPDATE Sales.SalesTerritory
    SET Name = @territory
```

I am really starting to go in circles and am not sure where I am going wrong or what my next steps need to be.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: `UPDATE` statements change the data in the database, are you sure the problem is described correctly?

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis I was just about asking the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like this, instead of the `UPDATE` statements:

```
SELECT * FROM Person.Address WHERE AddressLine1 = @address;
SELECT * FROM Person.StateProvince WHERE Name = @province;
SELECT * FROM Sales.SalesTerritory WHERE Name = @territory;
```

But if you don't yet know when to use `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `INSERT` or `DELETE` you need to have a crash course in Databases and SQL well before learning about stored procedures in my opinion.

Comment: Changed it up and now have results based on your previous advice.
It gives me back the address table and blanks on the other two tables. Do I need to do a couple of joins to get this to execute and return the results i need?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't have access to the AdventuresWork database. So if you could post some sample data perhaps we could guide you better.